# How to import a new font into a project - Angular 6

Tags: angular

I need to include new font family in my angular 6 project

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
```

import the google font in my scss file but it doesn't work well

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work well". Have you checked in the network tab that the font is being downloaded? Are you correctly referencing the font family in your css?

Comment: after importing have you used your font in your css/scss using @font-face syntax. and what king of error you are getting?

Comment: Better download the fonts to assets/fonts folder and import it from there, using online urls is against the laws of coding because it wont work in offline environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step #1**

Create a scss file with font face and place it somewhere, like in assets/fonts

**font_name.scss**

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: Futura Bk Bt;
    src: url("./FuturaBookfont.woff") format("woff");
}
```

**woff** file converter link https://www.font-converter.net/en

**Step #2**

Paste the .woff file into the  src url path.

**Step #3**

Include the scss file into your angular.json file

```
{
 ...
 "projects": {
 "project-name": {
  ...
   "architect": {
     "build": {
       ...
       "options": {
        ...
        "styles": [
          ...
          "src/assets/fonts/font_name.scss",
          ...
        ],
        ...
      },
      ...
    },
    ...,
    "test": {
      ...
      "options": {
        ...
        "styles": [
          ...
          "src/assets/fonts/font_name.scss",
          ...
        ],
        ...
      }
    },
    ...
   }
 },
}
```

**It is Also Used For All Fonts Include Paid Fonts Also(Ex: Futura Bk Bt,..)**

Comment: this looks good, but I don't know whether you are looking for answer or you want to post an answer? Your solution looks more brief then your question !!

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways of adding fonts in angular:

1. Install it with

```html
npm install roboto-fontface --save
```

and add it to  styles in .angular-cli.json:

```css
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css"
],
```

2. Insert it from the web

```html
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
```

and then use it in you scss file as Roboto.

> However, using CDN might cause some problems as Angular treats this as low priority and some browsers might fail to load the font. In that case the safest way is to go with the first way of doing it. [Here is an article that explains further this issue](https://medium.com/@aditya_tyagi/import-fonts-in-an-angular-app-the-easy-right-way-ae9e99cab551) and the comparison of CDN and hosting the fonts yourselve

Answer (score 0):

Try to import in index.html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: The Font Family is a paid version, so it doesn't works