# How to import font in CSS file using Single-SPA

Tags: angular, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I am using Single SPA with angular and I am trying to import a font in my css file using `src`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Effra";
  src: url("//example/assets/fonts/effra/Effra-BoldItalic.woff2")
      format("woff2"),
    url("//example/assets/fonts/effra/Effra-BoldItalic.woff")
      format("woff");
}
```

But since I am using Single-SPA, this won't work, So is there a specific path I should be using to get this import work?

Comment: Why do you have 2 urls?  And make sure you have the font file in the correct place.

Comment: @Mike different formats. and the path is correct but its different when it comes to single-spa

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60148649/9524445 try this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a new font into a project - Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60148455/how-to-import-a-new-font-into-a-project-angular-6)

Answer (score -3):

In your style.css file and include the font by referencing a path.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Oxygen";
    src: local("Oxygen"), url(./assets/fonts/Oxygen/Oxygen-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

Here I added a Oxygen font.
Now, you can use this font inside the components CSS files like this.

```
.container{
    font-family: "Oxygen", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Finally clear your browser cache and reload it.

Comment: This doesn't work in Single SPA, since Single SPA paths are different cuz it uses micro-frontends.

Comment: Then you can set the URL for your front-end asset path.is it right?

Comment: you can set it this way like `Localhost:8080/assets/etc..` however, it will be confusing later on when you deploy, But single SPA provides a function named assetUrl for situations like this, but you can't call it in CSS file of course.

Comment: If you copy-paste something verbatim from a page (https://reactgo.com/add-fonts-to-angular/), you should mention this. Otherwise this might be seen as plagiarism.